# Linq to SQL Object Class generation

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I wonder if there is a way to generate object class assembly from a database schema instead of manually create the classes.

Comment: That's exactly what a dbml file is.

Comment: Is there an easy way to generate dbml from a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using the:

- [Code Generation in LINQ to SQL.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399400.aspx)or
- [SqlMetal.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987.aspx): something like

> sqlmetal.exe  /server:.  /database:projectname /map:outputDB.xml
>   /code:Projectname.Domain.Entities.cs  /functions  /sprocs 
>   /namespace:Projectname.Domain